# Can I have a configurable for gift cards?

Tags: configurable-product, magento-1, ee-1.14, gift-card

I noticed this morning that there is a "gift card" product type. I've had a quick play with it and it looks like the product view template is ideal for this type of product, as it includes customisable prices and sender/recipient information fields etc.

Assuming I have ten different "designs" of gift cards, is there a way that I can group these "gift card" products under a configurable product with a "design" configurable attribute?

At the moment I can see how to create a single "gift card" product and have it display as I wish in the frontend, but I'd like to be able to use a configurable for this so the user can also choose a "design" from a list of ten.

**Note:** configurable attribute "design" is created, unique attribute set exists for these products, and the configuration is currently working fine with a configurable, many virtual products and some custom templates, but I'm looking to do more of this out-of-the-box if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible out of the box with EE as the documentation states you can only do the same operation with gift card type as simple products: http://docs.magento.com/m1/ee/user_guide/catalog/product-gift-card-create.html

I don't have an EE instance available right now but creating a configurable product and setting the associated products as gift cards don't work from my knowledge.

The only alternative you've got left is the custom module / extension way.

Comment: I'm fine with custom modules etc if required, just trying to understand what *is* required. Could a "custom option" or something act as a suitable replacement in this instance, so I might just have one "gift card product" with a custom option for my configurable attribute?

Comment: @RobbieAverill I think custom options could do it just give it a try

Comment: I gave it a go, but couldn't seem to get them to show up in the template... they're not specific to certain kinds of products are they?

Comment: @RobbieAverill I don't think they are but again I don't have an EE available right now so I may be wrong